# Timeout when generate excel for download

Tags: apache-poi, servlet-3.0

I am trying to export Excel using poi and servlet. code like this

```
        SXSSFWorkbook workbook = genrateExcel(id)
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        byte[] outArray = outputStream.toByteArray();
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        response.setContentLength(outArray.length);
        response.setHeader("Expires:", "0");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(excelFileName, "UTF-8"));
        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        outStream.write(outArray);
        outStream.flush();
        workbook.dispose();
        workbook.close();
```

But sometimes generating costs too much time,so i get a 504 timeout error.

I wonder how can I hold the connection until file is generated ?

UPDATE:
  thanks Gagravarr. I update the code  to this

```
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<SXSSFWorkbook> future = threadPool.submit(new Callable<SXSSFWorkbook>() {
        @Override
        public SXSSFWorkbook call() {
           return genrateExcel(id);
        }
    });
    SXSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    try {
        response.setHeader("Expires:", "0");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + URLEncoder.encode(excelFileName, "UTF-8"));
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int times = 0;
        while (times < 50) {
            if (future.isDone()) {
                workbook = future.get();
                break;
            }
            outStream.flush();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            times++;
        }
        workbook = workbook == null ? new SXSSFWorkbook() : workbook;
        workbook.write(outputStream);
        byte[] outArray = outputStream.toByteArray();
        response.setContentLength(outArray.length);
        outStream.write(outArray);
        outStream.flush();
        workbook.dispose();
        workbook.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But got a `ClientAbortException:  java.io.IOException` meanwhile Chrome report `the page isnot working ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` is sth wrong?

Comment: Open the output stream at the start, and have a background worker flush it from time to time until creation is done?

Comment: thanks @Gagravarr But there is still something wrong,I have update the question